# Dojo DND creating multiple items

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

I got a question to which I have no answer after a couple of hours of trying and googling :(

I've created three dojo.dnd.Source components. It is used to couple a user to a project so to the left I've got projects and to the right I've got my users and in the center I got a canvas. I set up the relevant creators and checkacceptance functions and all is well.

Onto the center canvas a user can drop a project which is shown as a div containing all related users as div elements. The other dndtype that can be dropped is the user type, in that case I want to empty the canvas and show all projects to which te dropped user is related. As soon as I drop a project or user on the canvas the creator function is called. The problem is that the creator function returns 1 element that should be dropped, if I drop a user I need to draw several elements onto the canvas so the creator method isn't fully covering this since it returns only one element.

To cope with the default behaviour I tried to manually add projects to the canvas and returning only one, I know it ain't pretty :S It's working but I'm confronted with strange behaviour, if I move a project on the canvas it is treated as a user in stead of a project.

Bottom line, is there a way that you guys know of to drop one item and create multiple. I was searching to trigger the drop event myself but to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The event you are looking for is Source's onDrop event. Check the API docs for some more events you could use: there is a onDropExternal and onDropInternal for use inside and between Stores.

```
require(["dojo/dnd/Source"], function(Source){
  var source = new Source({
     onDrop = function(source, nodes, copy)  {
       //called only on the current target, when drop is performed
       this.inherited(arguments); //execute the default onDrop function  
       //now add the node(s) to the other stores here
       //you might be able to just do something like: 
       source2.insertNodes(nodes);//but this is untested ;)
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Been there, I can get it to work that way as well but since it's a global subscription I didn't want to put source specific logic there. Was hoping there was a more standard way since I'm abusing a callback now for it :) I was looking for something more like a creator method that allows the return of nodelist in stead of a single node if it exists.. Thanks for the input!